Random Assignment of Email Addresses with Special Conditions
Given a series of email addresses, I need to randomly pair them with the condition that if A is to give a gift to B, then B must give a gift to A. If the number of email addresses is odd, the last three must be paired with each other (A with B, B with C, and C with A). I'm implementing this in MySQL with the following code:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CasoB(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    persons VARCHAR(50),
    personsToGive VARCHAR(50) 
);

INSERT INTO CasoB (persons, personsToGive) VALUES 
('a.tomas', NULL),
('g.rubio', NULL),
('a.pulido', NULL),
('m.fabrega.1', NULL),
('d.lazaro', NULL),
('c.albinya', NULL),
('b.gomez', NULL),
('j.espinoza', NULL),
('j.aguilera', NULL),
('j.da.silva.1', NULL),
('a.chamorro', NULL);

DELIMITER //

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GenerateRandomOrderB()
BEGIN
    DECLARE lineCount INT;

    -- Drop the temporary table if it exists
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS RandomOrderB;

    -- Create the temporary table
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RandomOrderB (
        id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        persons VARCHAR(50),
        RowNumber INT,
        TotalCount INT
    );

    -- Get the number of lines in CasoB
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO lineCount FROM CasoB;

    -- Insert data into the temporary table and get the total count
    INSERT INTO RandomOrderB (id, persons, RowNumber, TotalCount)
    SELECT  id, 
            persons,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RAND()) AS RowNumber,
            lineCount AS TotalCount
    FROM    CasoB;

    IF lineCount % 2 = 0 THEN
        -- Even number of records
        -- Pair the persons
        UPDATE CasoB
        SET personsToGive = (
            SELECT r2.persons
            FROM RandomOrderB AS r1
            INNER JOIN RandomOrderB AS r2
            ON r2.RowNumber = r1.RowNumber + (lineCount / 2)
            WHERE r1.id = CasoB.id
        );
    ELSE
        -- Odd number of records
        -- Pair all persons except the last three
        UPDATE CasoB
        SET personsToGive = (
            SELECT r2.persons
            FROM RandomOrderB AS r1
            INNER JOIN RandomOrderB AS r2
            ON r2.RowNumber = r1.RowNumber + (lineCount / 2)
            WHERE r1.id = CasoB.id
        );

        -- Pair the last three persons among themselves
        UPDATE CasoB
        SET personsToGive = persons
        WHERE id IN (
            SELECT id
            FROM (
                SELECT id
                FROM RandomOrderB
                ORDER BY RowNumber DESC
                LIMIT 3
            ) AS lastThree
        );
    END IF;
    
    -- Drop the temporary table when finished
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS RandomOrderB;
END //

DELIMITER ;

My question, I think that the code is correct, at least the part that randomizes the even numbers is like this
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RandomOrder;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RandomOrder (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    people VARCHAR(50),
    RowNumber INT,
    TotalCount INT
);

INSERT INTO RandomOrder (id, people, RowNumber, TotalCount)
SELECT 
    id,
    people,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RAND()) AS RowNumber,
    COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalCount
FROM CaseA;

UPDATE CaseA
SET peopleForGift = (
    SELECT r2.people
    FROM RandomOrder AS r1
    INNER JOIN RandomOrder AS r2
    ON r2.RowNumber = (r1.RowNumber % r1.TotalCount) + 1
    WHERE r1.id = CaseA.id
);

but when it comes to randomizing it to the odd number of people, do the randomization first of all the people except the last 3 and then randomize only those 3 peoplebut when it comes to randomizing it to the odd number of people, do the randomization first of all the people except the last 3 and then randomize only those 3 people

I don't think the assignment logic will work. ON r2.RowNumber = r1.RowNumber + (lineCount / 2) will result in only half of the rows to be assigned.

I'm still curious why the highest three ids should be grouped together but all the others put in random pairs; why don't you want the group of three to be randomly selected but you do want the pairs randomly selected?

WITH
cte1 (id, persons, personsToGive, rn) AS (
  SELECT id, persons, personsToGive, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND())
  FROM CasoB
  ),
cte2 (id, persons, personsToGive, rn, rnx) AS (
  SELECT id, persons, personsToGive, rn,
         CASE WHEN 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) MOD 2 FROM CasoB)
              THEN ((rn + 1) DIV 2) * 4 - 1 - rn
              ELSE CASE WHEN rn > 3 
                        THEN (rn DIV 2) * 4 + 1 - rn
                        ELSE (rn MOD 3) + 1
                        END
              END
  FROM cte1                              
  )
UPDATE CasoB
  JOIN cte2 cte21 ON CasoB.id = cte21.id
  JOIN cte2 cte22 ON cte21.rn = cte22.rnx
SET CasoB.personsToGive = cte22.persons;

fiddle

Yes, okay, but what I need you to do is have everyone except the last 3 play among themselves and then the 3 play among themselves 3

any ideas to get it?

@chamorro this does that.  Did you try it?

@ysth
Yes I have tried it and the last 3 cases do not give each other
(id persons personsToGive
1 a.tomas a.pulido
2 g.rubio c.albinya
3 a.pulido a.tomas
4 m.fabrega.1 d.lazaro
5 d.lazaro m.fabrega.1
6 c.albinya j.aguilera
7 b.gomez a.chamorro
8 j.espinoza j.da.silva.1
9 j.aguilera g.rubio
10 j.da.silva.1 j.espinoza
11 a.chamorro b.gomez)

These 3 should give each other a gift.
9 j.aguilera
10 j.da.silva.1
11 a.chamorro

@chamorro: it randomizes the list and groups three of them and pairs the rest.  table rows have no inherent order, so your "3 last" isn't possible. there is no order to be first or last in, unless you specify some means of ordering.

@ysth That's why I had put IDs on the people to be able to identify them but it doesn't work as I expected. Any ideas even if I have to change the entire code?

you should edit your question to indicate you want the three highest ids grouped together.  but why are all the others randomly grouped but not those three?  doesn't make any sense to me.  anyway, if you edit your question, Akina may chose to update his answer

kludging in this weird requirement gives https://dbfiddle.uk/Y0ZtEFfE

@ysth Thank you very much, you don't know what a favor you have done for me, this was a very specific thing that I had been looking for a solution for days

@chamorro what I need you to do is have everyone except the last 3 play among themselves and then the 3 play among themselves 3 The term "last 3" does not exist until you specify precisely what ordering must be used. When you have such definition (for example, "last 3 while ordering by their id column values") then simply edit 1st CTE and replace ORDER BY RAND() with according reversed sorting expression (for provided definition this will be ORDER BY id DESC).

@Akina aaaaaa I think I understand

Thank you very much for the clarification, I am starting with the SQL topic and at the moment we are not very friends
